# Recommended Mac anti-virus client

Tags: mac-osx, mac, anti-virus, security

What anti-virus client do you recommend for Macs used in an office setting? (I am not asking if you should run AV on Mac, I'm asking for client recommendations.)

Candidates:

- Sophos
- ClamxAV
- Others?

Comment: I suppose "OSX" isn't an answer? :-)

Comment: Back when I had a Mac, I ran ClamxAV on it.  I had no complaints about it.

Comment: There are viruses for OSx even though they are few and far between companies that are SOX/SAS70/etc compliant will have to document having AV no matter small the risk. As to what client I have no recommendation but I have seen Symantec AV on corporate Macs before. The tagline is *Top-selling security software product for Macintosh® systems from June 1998 through June 2009 so maybe something better came out that started stealing business in 2009 or maybe there just aren't newer statistics available yet.

Comment: This should be a wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Intego VirusBarrier](http://www.intego.com/virusbarrier/) and [Norton AntiVirus](http://www.symantec.com/norton/macintosh/antivirus) have generally been the best choices.

Comment: I have also good experience with Intego VirusBarrier

Comment: Do us a favor, and skip it.

Answer (score 0):

Norton has a solution

http://www.symantec.com/norton/macintosh/antivirus